# Return single row if date exist anywhere in table column

Tags: mysql

Following is mysql query in which i am detecteing if the current (All)month&(in current)year exist in the database date column or not. Query is working fine but its running for every row of the table separately and returning all the number of rows present in the table with the specific match for that row. What i wanna do is that the following query should return single row and tells if the given date exist (anywhere in date column) in the table or not . Kindly let me know how can i modify the following query to do this. Thanks

```
SELECT 
IF(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(dt_note_created),'%Y%m') =  CONCAT((DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y')),'01'),1,0) as jan,
IF(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(dt_note_created),'%Y%m') =  CONCAT((DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y')),'02'),1,0) as feb,
IF(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(dt_note_created),'%Y%m') =  CONCAT((DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y')),'03'),1,0) as mar,
IF(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(dt_note_created),'%Y%m') =  CONCAT((DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y')),'04'),1,0) as apr,
IF(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(dt_note_created),'%Y%m') =  CONCAT((DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y')),'05'),1,0) as may,
IF(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(dt_note_created),'%Y%m') =  CONCAT((DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y')),'06'),1,0) as jun,
IF(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(dt_note_created),'%Y%m') =  CONCAT((DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y')),'07'),1,0) as jul,
IF(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(dt_note_created),'%Y%m') =  CONCAT((DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y')),'08'),1,0) as aug,
IF(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(dt_note_created),'%Y%m') =  CONCAT((DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y')),'09'),1,0) as sep,
IF(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(dt_note_created),'%Y%m') =  CONCAT((DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y')),'10'),1,0) as oct,
IF(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(dt_note_created),'%Y%m') =  CONCAT((DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y')),'11'),1,0) as nov,
IF(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(dt_note_created),'%Y%m') =  CONCAT((DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y')),'12'),1,0) as decb
FROM Notes
```

**Output:**

```
jan | feb | Mar ....and so on... | nov | dec
 0     1     1                      0     1

0 and 1 are flags which are telling if the monthandyear exist in the whole column of date or not
```

Comment: Can you post the create table for this table?

Comment: @DukeSilver just create one table `date` with one coulmn `date` in and make query for that for the modification mentioned above. In the above query result is perfect but for specific rows not all table

Comment: @sємsєм Distinct has nothing to do with my requested question to be answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but if u only want to check if there is at least one date in your column matching current month and year, try

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM date
WHERE MONTH(dt_note_created) = MONTH(Now()) 
  AND YEAR(dt_note_created) = YEAR(Now())
```

this will return 0 if there is no such date and otherwise the number of dates in total.

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(dt_note_created)
FROM date
WHERE YEAR(dt_note_created) = YEAR(Now())
```

to get a list of the differnet month included in your date column.

it returns something like (for dates in Jan, Feb, Aug, Nov):

```
1
2
8
11
```

And as long as this number is less than 12 there is not at least one date in each month.

Comment: I have to search for all months in year not only single one

Comment: Do you mean a specific day of each month? I think i did not get the point right now.

Comment: No, for All months in year `jan,feb...Nov,Dec` like does jan2012 exist in Date column `DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m')` and so on....

Comment: now I get it. you need to know if there is at least one date in each month.

Comment: No, I need to know if the jan2012,feb2012... Dec2012 exist in the whole date column or not

Comment: Thanks now you got my point and gave me a good solution too thanks